# Getting duplication with inner join and left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to fetch following information for the table of the columns :

1) Primary key.

2) IsNullable

3) Is_Identity.

**Query :**

```
SELECT c.name 'Column Name',c.is_nullable,c.is_identity,ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key' FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[HumanResources].[Employee]')
```

I am working with [Adventure Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124438(v=sql.100).aspx) database but the problem here is I am getting `OrganizationNode` column 2 times and I am unable to understand the reason.

For other tables I am not getting this issue but I am only getting this problem for the table `[HumanResources].[Employee]`.

Below is the link to download database bak file :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nutfat17b73boav/AdvantureWorksSeScript.bak?dl=0

[image]

I have also tried `distinct` but because of that it shuffled up the ordering of the column as you can see in the second output. `BirthDate is coming at the top instead of BusinessEntityID.`

I would not like to use `distinct` as my below query is working fine with all other tables but I am not getting why it is giving duplicate columns in case of `[HumanResources].[Employee]` table or may be I have tested it with few tables and query may not work properly for few other databases.

I am not sure whether my query is correct or not to work in all the scenarios to fetch above 3 things(`pk,inullable etc.`) which I mention.

Comment: If you want to have a specific order your rows there is 1 and only 1 way to do that...with an order by clause. I didn't pull down a copy of your database. I don't understand what the issue is here. Perhaps you have more than 1 index or the index has more than 1 column?

Comment: So you want to list all the columns for the table and the where clause and show whether they are primary key, is null and identity?

Comment: is it possible that that column is used in more than one index? Add index name to your query as a column.

Comment: @SEarle Yes I want to get list of columns with information like primary key,isnull etc

Comment: @KeithL  More than 1 index means?sorry didn't understand this

Comment: @KeithL  More than 1 index means?sorry didn't understand this

Comment: Just had a look. OrganizationNode is in two indexes - IX_Employee_OrganizationNode and IX_Employee_OrganizationLevel_OrganizationNode

Comment: @SEarle so is it because of that I am getting duplication in organisationnode column??

Comment: You are getting duplication because you have a one to many relation between the two tables. That column is in the index table more than once. Think of an invoice with multiple line items. The invoice number (header) is on every line item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  name,
        is_identity,
        is_nullable,
        is_primary_key
FROM    (
            SELECT  c.name,
                    c.column_id,
                    c.is_identity,
                    c.is_nullable,
                    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key,0) is_primary_key,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.name) rn
            FROM    sys.columns c
                    JOIN sys.tables t
                        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic
                        ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                    LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i
                        ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
            WHERE   t.name = 'Employee'
        )keys
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY column_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can merge this 2 queries in to 1 so that I need to execute only 1 query??

Comment: This is messing up the ordering of my columns like when i add distinct keyword in my query.I want to get exact ordering 
of my columns like i have in my table.

Comment: Then you just need to add an ORDER BY clause with column you want.  Which column is that?

Comment: I've amended so the query is ordered in the same way as your original post which is by column_id in the sys.columns view